# WebSocket Client closing on connection

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, client

I am trying to build a standalone WebSocket client in Java that connects to a WebSocket Server in C#. I am using a Self-Signed Certificate that was generated for the WebSocket server. I'm able to connect to the WebSocket server in my Chrome browser using WSS without any issues. When trying to use the [TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) library, it does not work. The OnClose method is called immediately on connection.

I have a Self-Signed certificate in a *.pfx file generated that I use for the C# server and is imported to my Trusted Root store. I created a *.jks from this file using keytool (I think I've done this correctly). I am using keystore.jks which was generated by keytool in my code.

Here is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ChatClient chatclient = new ChatClient("wss://thomas.localnetwork.com:65120/wsserver?userId=Thomas", "Thomas", "1", "1", "L");
    // load up the key store
    String STORETYPE = "JKS";
    String KEYSTORE = "C:\\Users\\thomas\\Desktop\\keystore.jks";
    String STOREPASSWORD = "test12345";
    String KEYPASSWORD = "test";

    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance( STORETYPE );
    File kf = new File( KEYSTORE );
    ks.load( new FileInputStream( kf ), STOREPASSWORD.toCharArray() );

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance( "SunX509" );
    kmf.init( ks, KEYPASSWORD.toCharArray() );
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance( "SunX509" );
    tmf.init( ks );

    SSLContext sslContext = null;
    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance( "TLS" );
    sslContext.init( kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null );
    // sslContext.init( null, null, null ); // will use java's default key and trust store which is sufficient unless you deal with self-signed certificates

    SSLSocketFactory factory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();// (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

    chatclient.setSocketFactory( factory );

    chatclient.connectBlocking();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
    while ( true ) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if( line.equals( "close" ) ) {
            chatclient.closeBlocking();
        } else if ( line.equals( "open" ) ) {
            chatclient.reconnect();
        } else {
            ucm.send( line );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the exception I am receiving:

```
Closed connection on wss://laptop-thomas.compuflex1.com:65120/wsucm_deviceagent?userId=Thomas
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1906)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1870)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1815)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient.run(WebSocketClient.java:424)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:928)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    ... 3 more
```

Is there any way I could get more details about the handshake or what the actual problem is? The exception stack trace does not seem to be helpful at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that my local firewall was causing issues. I also found that I could install the certificate to Java's trusted root store.

Please note that each Java version (JDK and JRE) has its own "cacerts" file. Be sure to install to the correct one for your development or runtime environment. I was banging my head against the wall because it wasn't working in IntelliJ until I realized this.

1. [Install the certificate to the JVM trusted root store](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/how-to-import-a-public-ssl-certificate-into-a-jvm-867025849.html)
2. [Check if it's been installed correctly](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/unable-to-connect-to-ssl-services-due-to-pkix-path-building-failed-error-779355358.html)
3. Remove the keystore part of your code

Here's the change to my code after installing the certificate to the correct place.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ChatClient chatclient = new ChatClient("wss://thomas.localnetwork.com:65120/wsserver?userId=Thomas", "Thomas", "1", "1", "L");

    chatclient.connectBlocking();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
    while ( true ) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if( line.equals( "close" ) ) {
            chatclient.closeBlocking();
        } else if ( line.equals( "open" ) ) {
            chatclient.reconnect();
        } else {
            chatclient.send( line );
        }
    }
}
```